# How do I increment a variable by 1`for each run of a loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I have made a basic do while loop, I want to output car hire on the left and the voucherno on the right of the screen. If the user wants to repeat the process then the voucher no should increment by 1. Another thing is what is wrong with the while expression I have,
it says expected an expression before the = token.

---

```
   do {
        unsigned short voucherno=0;
        char processanother;
        cout<<"CAR HIRE"<<setw(4)<<setfill('0')<<"Voucher Number:"<<voucherno++;
        cout<<"Repeat again to test the loop Y/N?";
        cin>>processanother;
   }
    while(processanother!=='y'||process!=='Y');
```

Comment: make processanother  outside "do while" and change !== to !=

Comment: @qwr you meant `voucherno` global

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `for` loop or declare your variable outside the loop. Note that the condition in a `for` loop really can be any condition at all, it does not need to look at the same variables the other two expressions are using.

```
char processanother = 'y';
for (unsigned short voucherno=0;
     processanother=='y' || processanother =='Y';
     ++voucherno) {
  std::cout << ...
  std::cin >> processanother;
}
```

The way you have written your code, each iteration creates a new variable `voucherno`.

And what @qwr said: The operator is `!=`, not `!==`. But I believe you want `==` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you define voucherno in the do while loop, then voucherno is a local variable. Each loop it is defined as 0. So you won't get the actual counts. So define voucherno before the do-while loop instead.

In C++, if you want to, say, test if two variables are equal, you use `==` operator. And if you want to test if they are different, you use `!=` operator instead of `!==`. `!==` is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short voucherno=0;
do {

    char processanother;
    cout<<"CAR HIRE"<<setw(4)<<setfill('0')<<"Voucher Number:"<<voucherno++;
    cout<<"Repeat again to test the loop Y/N?";
    cin>>processanother;
}
while(processanother=='y'||process=='Y');
```

There is two mistake in your code.
  1. The voucherno variable is declared in side loop, so it will no show you incremented value, every time in loop it will get declared and assigned by zero so it will show zero(0)
 2. another mistake  in while condition there is no any operator in C++ like "!=="  as  you have used. If you want to check equality then use == and if you want to check not equal then use !=.

Thanks